# Asp.Net MVC 4 Generic Element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for the generic title, but i dont know how to call the element i want to create. Thats what i need... i tried to post image, but i dont get necessary privileges yet. So ill try to describe it.

Here on stackoverflow, on the question's page, after each title and summary there are some boxes displaying the tags from the questions.

I want the exactly same look, but instead of links, those boxes should act the same way as a Radio Button List. I can only choose one of then at a time and when pick one, the selected one ill get different style added to him. After submitting the form i should be able to recover de selected item in the controller.

I'm using Asp.Net MVC4 and the options that make the element will come from a controller.

Sorry for the question without code or something that i allready make. But i have this necessity and i dont even know if this sort of style or element have an specific name or keyword D.

Do you guys know from where to start with something (tutorials with similar final result ?) ? 
Thanks for the help and sorry for the bad english.

---

Code After Looking at the proposed answers' link

CSS Code

input[type=radio] { display: none;}

.rbLista span { font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;

font-size:12px; background: RGB(217,217,217); border: 1px solid RGB(217,217,217); }
.rbLista span:hover { border: 1px solid RGB(54,52,53); background: RGB(54,52,53); color: white; }

.rbLista input[type=radio]:checked + span { background: #D71712; color: #fff; border: 1px solid #D71712; }

.rbLista input[type=radio]:checked + span:hover { background: #D71712; }

and View Code

```
    <section class="rbLista">
        @foreach (var item in Model.ChamadoDetalhe.Transitos)
        {
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NovoTransito.Transito, @item.Text, new {                     @id = item.Text, @text = item.Text })<span>@item.Text</span>
            </label>
         }
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NovoTransito.Transito)
     </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something [like this](http://speckyboy.com/2012/09/11/classic-digg-style-radio-buttons-with-css-and-jquery/). Here's a [working demo](http://speckyboy.com/demo/digg-style-radio-buttons/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer. I looked at those examples and came up with what i need. I Updated my question with the solution i implemented. Thanks againg.